# Creating a Spinning Wheel in as3 that displays text when stopping

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6, roulette-wheel-selection

I am trying to create a spinning wheel that will display a coupon code when it stops on a particular color. Right now it displays color at the bottom of the page but I would like to add in specific coupon codes associated with each wheel snippet that appear when the wheel stops Thanks in advance!

Here is the current code:

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;    
    import flash.display.Shape;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import com.greensock.TweenMax;

public final class Main extends Sprite
{
    private var speed:Number = 0;
    private var paddles:Vector.<Sprite> = new Vector.<Sprite>();
    private var line:Shape;
    private var lastPaddle:String;

    public final function Main():void
    {
        paddles.push(wheel.p1, wheel.p2, wheel.p3, wheel.p4, wheel.p5, wheel.p6);
        listeners('add');
    }       

    private final function listeners(action:String):void 
    {
        if(action == 'add')
        {
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDraw);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, spinWheel);
        }
        else
        {
            stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDraw);
            stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, spinWheel);
        }
    }

    private final function startDraw(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        line = new Shape();
        addChild(line);

        line.graphics.moveTo(mouseX, mouseY);
        line.graphics.lineStyle(5, 0x00000, 0.3);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, drawLine);
    }

    private final function drawLine(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        line.graphics.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
    }

    private final function spinWheel(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, drawLine);
        listeners('rm');

        speed = line.height * 0.1; 
        removeChild(line);
        line = null;

        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, spin);
    }

    private final function spin(e:Event):void
    {
        /* Rotate Wheel */

        wheel.rotationZ += speed;

        /* Detect Value */

        for(var i:int = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            if(indicator.hArea.hitTestObject(paddles[i]))
            {
                lastPaddle = paddles[i].name;
            }
        }

        speed -= 0.1;

        if(speed <= 0)
        {
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, spin);
            speed = 0;
            run(lastPaddle);
            listeners('null');
        }
    }

    function run(action:String):void
    {
        switch(action)
        {
            case 'p1':
                TweenMax.to(colorMC, 0.5, {colorTransform:{tint:0x644D9B, tintAmount:1}});
                break;
            case 'p2':
                TweenMax.to(colorMC, 0.5, {colorTransform:{tint:0xFFCC00, tintAmount:1}});
                break;
            case 'p3':
                TweenMax.to(colorMC, 0.5, {colorTransform:{tint:0x4789C2, tintAmount:1}});
                break;
            case 'p4':
                TweenMax.to(colorMC, 0.5, {colorTransform:{tint:0xF15D5D, tintAmount:1}});
                break;
            case 'p5':
                TweenMax.to(colorMC, 0.5, {colorTransform:{tint:0x90CC6C, tintAmount:1}});
                break;
            case 'p6':
                TweenMax.to(colorMC, 0.5, {colorTransform:{tint:0xF29C69, tintAmount:1}});
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT::** This is the updated code per suggestions I added the `wheel.p1.addChild(myText);` at the end in the `function run(action:String):void` area. Is this the correct way of doing it or is there a better way. I also was unable to have the text show up in the live version.

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Shape;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
import com.greensock.TweenMax;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.text.TextField;

public final class Main extends Sprite;
{
    private var speed:Number = 0;
    private var paddles:Vector.<Sprite> = new Vector.<Sprite>();
    private var line:Shape;
    private var lastPaddle:String;

    public final function Main():void
    {
        paddles.push(wheel.p1, wheel.p2, wheel.p3, wheel.p4, wheel.p5, wheel.p6);
        listeners('add');
    }

    private final function listeners(action:String):void
    {
        if (action == 'add')
        {
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDraw);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, spinWheel);
        }
        else
        {
            stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDraw);
            stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, spinWheel);
        }
    }

    private final function startDraw(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        line = new Shape();
        addChild(line);

        line.graphics.moveTo(mouseX, mouseY);
        line.graphics.lineStyle(5, 0x00000, 0.3);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, drawLine);
    }

    private final function drawLine(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        line.graphics.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
    }

    private final function spinWheel(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, drawLine);
        listeners('rm');

        speed = line.height * 0.1;
        removeChild(line);
        line = null;

        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, spin);
    }

    private final function spin(e:Event):void
    {
        /* Rotate Wheel */

        wheel.rotationZ +=  speed;

        /* Detect Value */

        for (var i:int = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            if (indicator.hArea.hitTestObject(paddles[i]))
            {
                lastPaddle = paddles[i].name;
            }
        }

        speed -=  0.1;

        if (speed <= 0)
        {
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, spin);
            speed = 0;
            run(lastPaddle);
            listeners('null');
        }
    }

    function run(action:String):void
    {
        switch (action)
        {
            case 'p1' :
                TweenMax.to(colorMC, 0.5, {colorTransform:{tint:0x644D9B, tintAmount:1}});
                var myText:TextField = new TextField();
                myText.text = "10per";
                wheel.p1.addChild(myText);

                myText.textColor = 0xFF0000;
                myText.x = 350;
                myText.y = 485;
                break;
            case 'p2' :
                TweenMax.to(colorMC, 0.5, {colorTransform:{tint:0xFFCC00, tintAmount:1}});
                break;
            case 'p3' :
                TweenMax.to(colorMC, 0.5, {colorTransform:{tint:0x4789C2, tintAmount:1}});
                break;
            case 'p4' :
                TweenMax.to(colorMC, 0.5, {colorTransform:{tint:0xF15D5D, tintAmount:1}});
                break;

            case 'p5' :
                TweenMax.to(colorMC, 0.5, {colorTransform:{tint:0x90CC6C, tintAmount:1}});
                break;

            case 'p6' :
                TweenMax.to(colorMC, 0.5, {colorTransform:{tint:0xF29C69, tintAmount:1}});
                break;
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so you don't have any problem or error you just want some code done for you?

Comment: I'm fairly new to as3 and was looking for some guidance as to how to do it!

Comment: What have you tried? What's the problem? Add a new `TextField` with the coupon code.

Comment: @batman The problem is that i have 6 different coupon codes that I need to show up once the spinner stops on a particular wedge. So i don't know where to put the `TextField` to have it show up correctly for each wedge, if that makes sense. I can attach a Jpeg of what the wheel looks like.

Comment: just add the text fields as children of the wedges.  eg `wheel.p1.addChild(myTextField)`

Comment: @Batman I have used your suggestions but wasn't sure where to put it to have it show up after the wheel has stopped. I have edited my original post to show where I put it. The current location of it doesn't appear to have it show up in the live version

Comment: You could just put a text field under the wheel in FlashPro, give it an instance name, and set the value in your switch statement.   What you are doing should work though, is it not?

Comment: @Batman This worked how I wanted it thanks so much for your guidance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code that worked how I needed it to! Thanks to those who helped.

```
package 
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import com.greensock.TweenMax;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.text.TextField;

public final class Main extends Sprite
{
    private var speed:Number = 0;
    private var paddles:Vector.<Sprite> = new Vector.<Sprite>();
    private var line:Shape;
    private var lastPaddle:String;

    public final function Main():void
    {
        paddles.push(wheel.p1, wheel.p2, wheel.p3, wheel.p4, wheel.p5, wheel.p6);
        listeners('add');
    }

    private final function listeners(action:String):void
    {
        if (action == 'add')
        {
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDraw);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, spinWheel);
        }
        else
        {
            stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDraw);
            stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, spinWheel);
        }
    }

    private final function startDraw(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        line = new Shape();
        addChild(line);

        line.graphics.moveTo(mouseX, mouseY);
        line.graphics.lineStyle(5, 0x00000, 0.3);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, drawLine);
    }

    private final function drawLine(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        line.graphics.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
    }

    private final function spinWheel(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, drawLine);
        listeners('rm');

        speed = line.height * 0.1;
        removeChild(line);
        line = null;

        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, spin);
    }

    private final function spin(e:Event):void
    {
        /* Rotate Wheel */

        wheel.rotationZ +=  speed;

        /* Detect Value */

        for (var i:int = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            if (indicator.hArea.hitTestObject(paddles[i]))
            {
                lastPaddle = paddles[i].name;
            }
        }

        speed -=  0.1;

        if (speed <= 0)
        {
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, spin);
            speed = 0;
            run(lastPaddle);
            listeners('null');
        }
    }

    function run(action:String):void
    {
        switch (action)
        {
            case 'p1' :
                TweenMax.to(colorMC, 0.5, {colorTransform:{tint:0x644D9B, tintAmount:1}});

                    var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
                        myFormat.size = 30;


                    var myText:TextField = new TextField();
                        myText.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;
                        myText.text = "10% off your order with coupon code:perc10";
                        addChild(myText);

                        myText.textColor = 0xFFFFFF;
                        myText.width = 624;
                        myText.height = 41;
                        myText.x = 43;
                        myText.y = 457;
                break;
            case 'p2' :
                TweenMax.to(colorMC, 0.5, {colorTransform:{tint:0xFFCC00, tintAmount:1}});
                    var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
                        myFormat.size = 27;


                    var myText:TextField = new TextField();
                        myText.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;
                        myText.text = "$5 off when you spend $20+ with coupon code:5iveoff";
                        addChild(myText);

                        myText.textColor = 0x6D6D6D;
                        myText.width = 676;
                        myText.height = 38;
                        myText.x = 22;
                        myText.y = 459;

                break;
            case 'p3' :
                TweenMax.to(colorMC, 0.5, {colorTransform:{tint:0x4789C2, tintAmount:1}});
                    var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
                        myFormat.size = 30;


                    var myText:TextField = new TextField();
                        myText.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;
                        myText.text = "20% off your order with coupon code:2ZERO";
                        addChild(myText);

                        myText.textColor = 0xFFFFFF;
                        myText.width = 618;
                        myText.height = 41;
                        myText.x = 43;
                        myText.y = 458;


                break;
            case 'p4' :
                TweenMax.to(colorMC, 0.5, {colorTransform:{tint:0xF15D5D, tintAmount:1}});
                    var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
                        myFormat.size = 27;


                    var myText:TextField = new TextField();
                        myText.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;
                        myText.text = "$10 off when you spend $30+ with coupon code:10doll";
                        addChild(myText);

                        myText.textColor = 0xFFFFFF;
                        myText.width = 672;
                        myText.height = 38;
                        myText.x = 20;
                        myText.y = 459;

                break;

            case 'p5' :
                TweenMax.to(colorMC, 0.5, {colorTransform:{tint:0x90CC6C, tintAmount:1}});
                    var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
                        myFormat.size = 30;


                    var myText:TextField = new TextField();
                        myText.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;
                        myText.text = "15% off your order with coupon code:fifperc";
                        addChild(myText);

                        myText.textColor = 0xFFFFFF;
                        myText.width = 618;
                        myText.height = 41;
                        myText.x = 50;
                        myText.y = 458;

                break;

            case 'p6' :
                TweenMax.to(colorMC, 0.5, {colorTransform:{tint:0xF29C69, tintAmount:1}});
                    var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
                        myFormat.size = 27;


                    var myText:TextField = new TextField();
                        myText.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;
                        myText.text = "$15 off when you spend $40+ with coupon code:fifdolla";
                        addChild(myText);

                        myText.textColor = 0xFFFFFF;
                        myText.width = 672;
                        myText.height = 38;
                        myText.x = 15;
                        myText.y = 459;;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

}